# Переписать часть кода из C++ на Python

Tags: python, c++, бинарное-дерево

как я могу переписать этот кусок кода на C++ в Python

```
void treeFork(treeNode* root)
{
    if (root)
    {
        treeFork(root->left);
        if (root->left && root->right)
            cout << root->data << " ";
        treeFork(root->right);
    }
}
```

вот мой код на Python

```
class Node:
   def init(self, data):
      self.left = None
      self.right = None
      self.data = data

   def insert(self, data):
      if self.data:
         if data < self.data:
            if self.left is None:
               self.left = Node(data)
            else:
               self.left.insert(data)
         elif data > self.data:
            if self.right is None:
               self.right = Node(data)
            else:
               self.right.insert(data)
         else:
            self.data = data

def fork(root):
    if root is None:
        return 0 
    else:
        if root.left and root.right:
            print(root.data)
    
m, *n = map(int, input().split())
root = Node(m)
for i in n:
    if i!=0:
        root.insert(i)
 
print(str(fork(root)))
```

мне нужно переписать часть с функцией def fork(root)

суть в том что код должен вывести все разветвления дерева. в моем коде выводит только разветвление из корня, но он не идет дальше. не знаю как написать, что бы код шел дальше по дереву
спасибо за помощь

Comment: Что за дурацкая затея переносить код из  эффективного языка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А куда вызовы функции самой себя потеряли?

```
def fork(root):
    if root is None:
        return 0 
    else:
        fork(root.left)              # <<<<
        if root.left and root.right:
            print(root.data)
        fork(root.right)             # <<<<
```